# How to redirect Raspbmc audio output to Android device?

Tags: raspbmc, audio

I am using **Raspberry Pi** as a **HTPC** using **Raspbmc**. I control Raspbmc using the **Yatse** remote control app installed on Android smartphone and tablet.

There are times when I wish I could watch TV using Raspbmc without disturbing everyone in the home. Is it possible to **redirect** the audio output of Raspbmc back to my **Android** smartphone or tablet? I could listen to the audio using headphones plugged into the phone or tablet.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is a way to do this as a hack, but you are able to do this using the Yatse remote for android. I think the streaming feature is only available through the unlocked version, but it does what you are looking for.